# How to take a nested list as input from user?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to take a nested list like this from user.
`[(2, 5), (1, 2), (4, 4), (2, 3), (2, 1)]`

> 6. Write a Python program to get a list, sorted in increasing order by the last element
>      in each tuple from a given list of non-empty tuples. Go to the editor
>
>    Sample List : `[(2, 5), (1, 2), (4, 4), (2, 3), (2, 1)]`
>
>    Expected Result : `[(2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 4), (2, 5)]`

```
def sorted_lst(lst):
    nlst = []
    for i in lst:
        if i[1] < (i+1)[1]:
            nlst += i
        else:
            nlst += i+1
    return nlst
ui = int(input("How many input?"))
ulst = []
for i in range(ui):
    ui1 = list(map(int,input("Enter elements: ").split(',')))
    ulst += ui1
print(ulst)
print(sorted_lst(ulst))
```

Comment: what's the logic for expected output ?

Comment: What is the actual result, and what is wrong with it? Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
ui1 = list(map(int,input("Enter elements: ").split(',')))
```

turns each user input line of the form `x,y` into the 2-list [x,y]. But your problem statement says it should be a tuple:

```
ui1 = tuple(map(int,input("Enter elements: ").split(',')))
```

This line:

```
ulst += ui1
```

does not append the user's input tuple as a new element in the list `ulst`. It appends the *elements* of the input tuple, so all you end up with is a list of integers of length `2*ui` instead of a list of 2-tuples of length `ui`. Use `ulst.append(ui1)` instead.

Finally, unless your assignment calls for it, do *not* write your own sort function.

```
print (sorted(ulst,key = lambda a: a[1]))
```

Your function `sorted_lst` is a good illustration of why not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to python. I've just started learning a few days ago but I think I know how to take nested list as input from the user. Try this in python 3.

```
ulst = [[int(input(f"Enter row {i+1}, column {j+1}: ")) for j in range(2)] for i in range(5)]
```

[Here is how the output looks like in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUiww.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

a=[(2, 5), (1, 2), (4, 4), (2, 3), (2, 1)]
for j in range (1,len(a)):
for i in range(len(a)-j):
if a[i][1]>a[i+1][1] :
b=a[i]
a[i]=a[i+1]
a[i+1]=b
print(list(a), end="")

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!